# Term for similarity transformation which is not a translation

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

What's the best (i.e. most concise) term to refer to an orientation-preserving similarity transformation which is not a translation? Here are some descriptions I could think of, but all of them feel rather bulky. I hope they are as equivalent to one another as I think they are, and I hope there is something simpler equivalent to all of them.

- a [direct similarity transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29) which is not a [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) (by a non-zero displacement)
- a [homothety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) (possibly with factor $1$) followed by [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) (with possibly zero angle)
- an orientation-preserving similarity with at least one [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29)
- a direct similitude with a well-defined [similitude center](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimilitudeCenter.html), or the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)
- what $z\mapsto a(z-c)+c$ describes in the [complex plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), for some fixed $a,c\in\mathbb C$ (with $a\neq 0$)

As a native German, I tend to think about this using the German term “[Drehstreckung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehstreckung)” which literally translates to “rotation-dilation”. I'm somewhat surprised by the difficulty I have in finding an exact English translation for this concept.

Comment: I can't seem to think of an official term, either, although I've certainly employed the concept before. Hmmmm ... Well, we have ["roto-reflections"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_rotation), so why not  "roto-dilations" or "roto-similarities"?

Comment: “Drehstreckung” is a magnificent word! Scaled-rotation perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your literal translation of *Drehstreckung*, "rotation-dilation", is the term that my high-school textbook used for this kind of transformation. Sure enough, I see the exact same terminology in [lecture notes for a course in Linear Algebra with Probability at Harvard](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture08.pdf) and in [a "MATLAB help page" for linear-algebra students at Johns Hopkins](http://www.mathematics.jhu.edu/matlab/2-5.html).

Comment: Both references you link to describe the restricted situation of a linear transformation, i.e. always using the origin as the center of rotation and dilation. That interpretation is sometimes used in Germany for *Drehstreckung* as well, so perhaps the English term is used in both senses, too?

Comment: Both references use $2\times2$ matrices to describe their transformations, which forces them to have a fixed point at the origin. (Translations are not even among the transformations they can describe.) I think my high-school textbook's definition was not limited in that way but my memory of that is many years old. It would be interesting to find such a taxonomy for more general linear transformations in an available resource.

Answer (score -1):

It could be  *Dilation , Dialation, Dialatation* etc.. It may be  general extension or reduction accompanied by  *Rotations*  applicable to vectors of a *group* of lines or objects .

(Googling in the subject of Mechanics of materials and compressible Fluid mechanics one may encounter more generalized terminology in  reference to Stress-Strain theorems.)

In the special 2 dimensions case it represents

- Quotient of *two* complex numbers:

  $$  Z_1  = r_1 \cdot e^{t_1} ,\; Z_2  = r_2 \cdot e^{t_2},$$

  $$ | Z_1 / Z_2| = (r1/r2) \cdot e^{ (t1-t2)}. $$

where quotient $(r_1/r_2)$ is the reduced scaling or dilation/dimunition factor and argument $ (t_1-t_2) $ is amount of rotation/Drehung as a difference.

In the same sense it represents what happens to

- Product of complex numbers as well.

  $$ | Z_1 \cdot Z_2| = (r1\cdot r2) \cdot e^{ (t1+t2)}. $$

where now product  $(r_1 r_2)$ is the increased scaling or dilation/Streckung factor and argument $ (t_1 + t_2) $ is amount of rotation as a sum required to reach the new position of resultant vector in the Complex plane, Gauss or Argand diagram.

May be term like Coupled Dilatory Rotation express it.

Answer (score -2):

Not entirely sure, but there are some elements of Mobius Transformation.

Comment: Möbius transformation is definitely not the term I'm after, since on the one hand a general Möbius transformation is not a similarity, and on the other hand a translation is a special case of a Möbius transformation.

Answer (score -2):

I think that what you're looking for is simply called "affinity".

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation):

> Examples of affine transformations include translation, scaling, homothety, similarity transformation, reflection, rotation, shear mapping, and compositions of them in any combination and sequence.

Comment: The term “affinity” is even more generic than “similarity”, so it includes anisotropic scaling and shearing, which I don't want and which are not similarities, while also including translations which I want to exclude but which are included in similarities. So no, this is going in the wrong direction; I want something more specific than similarity, not more general.